# How do I delete a specific Parse Object's row within IBACTION?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a Parse object called annotation with a title class that I store in the Parse database. When the user clicks a certain button, I want to be able to remotely delete the row of the annotation object that has a specified "title".  How can I do this? I've seen code that declares "var query = new Parse.Query(myObject);" But I get an error trying to do this.

Comment: Are you displaying your results in. UITableView?

Comment: No. I gather all the objects in viewdidload for my mapView. And display all the annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the title (i.e., not the object) use a query to determine the specific object (row) you want to delete, then delete it. E.g.:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyClassName"];
[query whereKey:@"title" equalTo:theTitleString];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
  if (object) {
        [object deleteInBackground];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to retrieve object with title %@.", theTitleString);
  }
}];
```

The above assumes there is only one object with the given title.

You can also use `[object deleteEventually];` in place of the `deleteInBackground` method which will work even if the device does not have an internet connection at the time the user wants it to be deleted.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work anymore. It says "Expected expression in container literal"